# Git: How to untrack a file from remote repository but still keep it in all developer's local repository?

Tags: git

`git rm --cached mylogfile.log` can untrack `mylogfile.log` from repository while still keeping it in my local repository.

However, if other developer pull from the remote repository after I commmited, they will lost that file in their local repository.

The scenario is that I have committed a should-not-commit file, e.g., a machine special file to remote repository. I'd like to fix the wrong without affect other developers. Of course I cannot make a commit like `git rm --cached mylogfile.log` and then all the ohter developer lost their files.

If I use `git update-index --assume-unchanged`, the file will still be tracked by git, which is not what I want.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: You will also have the situation where setting up a new developer workstation won't have the file to begin with. Is the file contents really that important?

Answer (score 5):

In Git, *tracked* means "in the index".  Untracked means "not in the index".

While there is only one (hence the [definite article "the"](http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/)) index, the index is related to the *current commit*.  Every time you check out any particular commit—including `git checkout somebranch`, which checks out the *tip* commit of the named branch—you are telling Git to remove, from the index and work-tree, any version of any file that's different from the target commit, and insert, into the index and work-tree, the version of that file that goes with the target commit.

Suppose, then, that you're on a commit whose hash ID is `a4ef00d`, and you tell Git to check out a different commit whose ID is `1c0ffee`.  If file `mylogfile.log` exists in commit `a4ef00d` but not in commit `1c0ffee`, Git must *remove* the file from the index and work-tree.  Now the file is no longer tracked—but it's not there at all.

Now that you're on `1c0ffee`, if you `git checkout a4ef00d`, Git must put *into* the index and work-tree the version of `mylogfile.log` that's in `a4ef00d`.  Now the file is tracked again, and the version in your work-tree is the version that's in `a4ef00d`.

**This is always true, no matter what else you do:  Suppose a file *is* in at least one commit and *is not* in at least one other commit.  When you move from a commit that has it, to one that does not, Git will remove it from index and work-tree.  When you move from any commit that does not have it, to one that does, Git will put it back into the index and work-tree.**

This means that having a file be both tracked and untracked—which *is* possible—will cause Git to remove or re-create the file at times.  You *cannot* stop this process.  The tracked-ness or untracked-ness of the file will depend on which commit you check out, i.e., what you tell Git to copy into the index.

#### The index version can differ from either the current commit or the work-tree

In fact, the index is where you build the *next* commit to make.  This is one of the reasons that is its own thing, separate from "the current commit".  You may make changes to the index contents; these changes are "staged" for the *next* commit.  You do not *have to* stage work-tree changes; such changes are *unstaged* but still present, and show up as "modified but not staged".

Setting either `--assume-unchanged` or `--skip-worktree` tells Git not to look to see whether the index and work-tree versions differ.  Hence the index version can be left matching a previous commit, for however many new commits you make.  *But for either bit to become set, there must be an entry in the index.*  This means that the file must currently be tracked.

**If the file is tracked, it gets committed.**  Each new commit you make saves every file that is in the index, in the form it has right now in the index.  You cannot stop this process either.

#### The only real solution to this dilemma is to remove the file

Once you remove the file (`git rm mylogfile.log`), the file will be gone from *both* the index *and* the work-tree.  You can now commit the result, and the new commit lacks the file because it is not in the index.

Now that the file is not in the index, you can restore it to the work-tree.  It is now *untracked*.  It will stay that way—untracked, but present in the work-tree—as long as you do not put the file back into the index.  Now you must avoid `git add`-ing it, and *also* `git checkout`-ing an old commit that has it.

Of course, you will probably want to save it somewhere while you remove and commit.  The simplest method is to copy it somewhere outside of Git, `git rm` the file, commit, and then copy it back into place.  You can use `git rm --cached` to remove it from the index, without removing it from the work-tree, as a sort of short-cut for this process—but you are in effect saving the file outside of the repository.  Remember this for the steps below.

(You can now get Git to stop complaining that it *is* untracked by listing the file in a `.gitignore` file.  This has the primary effect of making Git stop complaining.  It also prevents Git from automatically `git add`-ing the file when you add "all" files or a directory containing the file—which, as we have seen, causes the file to become tracked.  **If a file is tracked, a `.gitignore` entry for it has no effect.**)

#### The file now gets removed on various operations

As we already noted above, if you move to a commit that *does* have the file, the file goes into the index and work-tree.  (If there is already a file with the same name in the work-tree, Git will make you move that file out of the way first.)

As you also noted:

> However, if other developer pulls from the remote repository after I commmited, they will lose that file in their local repository.

More precisely, if someone else obtains your commit that *lacks* the file (so that it is untracked), they now have the situation we mentioned above: they have commits that have the file, and commits that lack the file.  If they move (as in `git checkout`) from one commit that has the file, to one that does not, Git will remove the file, from both index and work-tree.

The `git pull` command, however, does not simply run `git checkout`.  It runs *two* Git commands.  The first one is `git fetch`, which obtains commits from a remote (another Git).  The second one depends on what you tell Git to do:

- `git pull` will run `git merge` by default.  This does either a regular merge, or a fast-forward "merge" (which is not really a merge).
- `git pull` can run `git rebase` instead, if you tell it to.  This is more complex than `git merge`, but amounts to doing a series of `git cherry-pick` operations to copy their original commits to come after yours.  One of these will attempt to combine (i.e., merge) their work with your "delete the log file" commit, after doing a `git checkout` of your commit.

Using either of these commands—`git merge` or `git rebase`—will thus result in Git wanting to remove the file from the index and work-tree, similar to what happens with a straight `git checkout`, but with these differences:

- If their commits *modify* (save a new/different version of) `mylogfile.log`, they will see a "modify/delete conflict", which they must resolve by deleting `mylogfile.log` (after first saving anything they want saved, somewhere else).
- If not (their committed version of `mylogfile.log` matches what is in the "merge base"), then either their work-tree version of `mylogfile.log` matches the committed version (and Git will go ahead and remove the file) or it does not (and Git will complain, and they must save anything they want saved, somewhere else, and then remove the file so that Git may proceed).

Once they have a commit—a merge commit, or their own rebased commits—that no longer has the file, they are in the same shape you were in: the file is now gone from both index and work-tree.  They can now *restore* it to the work-tree (but *not* to the index) and maintain it as an untracked file, just as you did.

#### There is no way around this work

The only way to avoid all this work is not to commit (and hence track) the file.  But someone already did commit (and hence track) the file.  Now everyone must perform this extra work.  Note that *everyone* must do this—that is, save the work-tree-only version elsewhere—*every* time they cross from a commit that does *not* have the file, into one that *does* have the file.  There is no way around this, because someone mistakenly committed the file in the past, and Git stores every commit forever.

#### Well, there *is* one way around this work, but it involves doing this work

You can "rewrite history": change your repository to a new, different repository in which no one has ever committed this file.  Now the mistake has never been made in the first place.  The problem is, you must now get everyone who was using the old repository, to switch to this new, different repository.

To rewrite history like this, you can use `git filter-branch`, or [The BFG](https://www.google.com/#q=git+bfg+site:stackoverflow.com).  Search for existing examples; there are plenty.

Note that while you are doing this switching, you must do a little bit of extra work: copy the log file from the old repository that has the mistake, into the work-tree of the new repository that does not.  So you are not really avoiding the work after all: you are just changing the time at which you do it.

Comment: where is the tl;dr part?

Comment: @Ace: the TL;DR is that it cannot be solved. Not very helpful. There are workarounds, and each one has its limitations and problem situations, so you must understand what Git does and pick one of those.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this command:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <file>
```

This will make git ignore any changes you've made locally to that file. You can `git push` without worrying about your local version being shared with others.

You can also often `git pull` without any problems; however, if the upstream version of this `<file>` is changed, i.e. the "correct" version has an update, then when you try to do a `git pull`, you'll see an error message about your local changes that would be overwritten by the pull.

To resolve this, you'll need to "unskip" the `<file>`, and stash the changes you've made locally. You can then pull the lastest, pop your stashed local version, fix any merge conflicts you get, and finally "skip" the file again:

Steps in this situation are:

```
1. git update-index --no-skip-worktree <file>
2. git stash
3. git pull
4. git stash pop
5. **handle any conflicts, re-apply any local-only changes you need**
6. git update-index --skip-worktree <file>
```

When a  is "skipped", the changes will be made in your working directory but running `git status` will show no changes made. To see which files have these skipped changes, you can run this command:

```
git ls-files -v | grep ^S
```

Which lists out all files verbosely (i.e. with their status flags at the beginning of the line. Then you search through those results with `grep`, looking only for the files with the status flag of capital S at the beginning of the line for that file (i.e. `^S`).